# How can I send a message to the Microsoft bot from within the bot so that the message will go through the dialog flow with corresponding response?

Tags: node.js, typescript, botframework, direct-line-botframework

The title of this should really be "how can I make the bot respond gracefully when something wipes out context or there is a server restart while someone is using the bot.  A. that is confusing and B. I need to plan this in parts so logically this would be the first part.

1. Without using directline, and maybe I have to be preferably without, how can I T up a message that is to the bot from the user just the same way I would talk to the bot in the client.  For example when I say 'hello' in the client, the bot then processes that information and responds via my dialogs.

I want to "pre" send a message to the bot so it elicits a response proactively. Now this isn't proactive messaging because that is another user coming into the bot and speaking to the client which is not what I want.

So again, how can I send a message to the bot from within the bot.

2. I want to do this for this reason: If the server shuts off or the person losses their context for some reason and they are already inside of the bot they have to reenter into the bot. Specifically, it is as if the are "restarting" the conversation. But, as in the emulator when you restart the conversation you are reentering into the bot and you are reconnecting/restarting the user.  In this case you are doing neither. You are just there... and the next time you type the pathway should already exist.

In my case it is like the context was wiped out and has to reestablish itself and then you can proceed to talk to the bot.

The affect on the user experience is this: they type text and the bot ignores and it essentially restarts and then they would have to type the text again.

Answer (score 0):

What state store are you using? If you are using Memory storage, then the behavior you are seeing is expected. Memory storage is volatile and temporary. You need to use a persistent and more robust state store (Cosmos, Azure Blob). By doing so, the "place" that a user is in (in conversation. within a waterfall dialog for example) is kept. Typically by ConversationState.

See here for more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

There's not a way to do exactly what you are asking. Proactive messages are the closest. But proactive messages aren't exactly for the situation of another user coming into the bot. They are typically used in a situation where something external can trigger a message to a user (a weather report or a stock hitting a threshold, for example). With proactive messages you would definitely want some sort of persistent state store.